# .NET garbage collection not working properly here?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

We had an image conversion script running on .NET 4.0, IIS 7, ASP.NET, 4 GB server RAM that resizes large images and thus needs a lot of memory.

The first script increased memory usage to almost 100%, leaving virtually nothing for the SQL Server that was also running (which gave up memory until running on 20 MB instead the usual 900 MB).

In the second script we added a GC.Collect() and (to be sure) a one sec thread sleep after each cycle, and everything went back to normal.

Question: isn't that a flaw in the .NET memory management? Shouldn't the system take a closer look at what's happening with the available memory, slow things down and clean up?

Comment: why are you running anything but SQL server on a server?

Comment: Just like "SELECT isn't broken" .NET Garbage collection isn't broken....

Comment: I bet you the .net garbage collector is doing it's job properly an you have an managed leak

Comment: If you configure SQL Server to have, say, 500 or 900 MB memory minimum, what happens then?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: it's a rented dedicated webserver, running IIS and SQL Server (and a few other things). A standard setup, I believe (of course it'd be preferable to have two servers, but in this case there is no performance need in everyday business). Secondly, I never said GC "is broken", but there ARE bugs in the IT world, now and then...

Comment: @Stormenet: I doubt that. For one thing I doubt the existance of a leak in that rather simple code, but even IF there was a leak, calling GC.Collect() shouldn't be handling things differently than the automated garbage collection.

Comment: @Damien: good idea, thx. I can't test that right now, but I set a minimum memory of 500  MB anyway, for next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.aspx):

> Garbage collection happens
>   automatically when a request for
>   memory cannot be satisfied using
>   available free memory.

I assume this situation hasn't been satisfied as SQL Server is backing down instead.  As for it being a bug; the docs would suggest this is by design.

Comment: True, but isn't also true that "Garbage collection happens automatically" only if there is time for that? What if the server is too busy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes garbage collection does its job when memory is not enough for the next operation. But.

Objects which are declared global or being used by global objects are unaffected by GC. So try to keep your objects local if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a flaw in the .Net memory management. We would need your code to be sure.

But I would first look into your code for cases where disposable resources are not disposed properly. This is known to cause memory leaks, and is the reason why the IDisposable interface exists.

Comment: We have disposed of the objects used - Image and Bitmap have been initialized in using brackets. Still, because GC.Collect() is working properly, doesn't that prove that the objects have been disposed properly?