# Is GC working properly?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET garbage collection not working properly here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354671/net-garbage-collection-not-working-properly-here)

I've tested the following code. 
when the button is clicked, objects are created and add them to the list. When  another a button is clicked, the list is cleared

GC is destroying the objects, but memory usage does not decrease. 
Why? Is there something wrong?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<MyModel> MyList;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyList = new List<MyModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList = new List<MyModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            MyList.Add(new MyModel { ID = i, Description = "Model Id : " + i.ToString() });
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Complate!");
    }

    private void button1_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Clear();
        MyList = null;
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    ~MyModel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Description);
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: GC is not guaranteed to free memory immediately. Generally the garbage collector waits for awhile before doing a garbage collection, and there are like three generations of GC that take place at different times, depending on the age of the objects being freed.

Comment: How are you tracking memory usage? You may find the answers to this question useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331389/c-sharp-thread-not-releasing-memory

Comment: Even if the GC decides to collect your objects, it might not release the memory back to the OS, and you may not see any difference by using external tools (e.g. taskmanager).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose you own a warehouse. You store boxes in the warehouse. Some of the boxes are garbage, so periodically you throw them out. **The square footage of the warehouse does not get smaller.**

If what you're measuring is the total number of memory pages committed to the process, then you're not measuring the number of boxes in the warehouse, you're measuring the square footage of the warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

The .Net garbage collector only runs when there's memory pressure.  In normal operation for many programs, memory usage will just continually increase until you quit the program, provided you have enough RAM for that.  You can explicitly ask it to perform a GC, but that's still just a suggestion.

Comment: RAM has little to do with it. Remember, RAM and address space are two completely different things.